# Odoo [OpenERP] Custom module KeyError issue

Tags: odoo

I am trying to add my own custom made module in odoo for test purpose. However, I am continuously getting the below error. Below is how my code looks like. Please help in this regard

> **_init**.py

```
import select_custom
```

> select_custom.py

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class select_custom(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'select.custom'

    _columns = {
        'productChoose' : fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Product Choose')
        }
```

> select_custom_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="view_custom_tick_box_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.custom.tick.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">select.custom</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="date_order" position="after">
                    <field name="productChoose"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 574, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 310, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 113, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 307, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 803, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 241, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 450, in button_immediate_install
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 241, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 498, in _button_immediate_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 370, in new
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 152, in load_module_graph
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 163, in load
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 595, in _build_model
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150621\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 102, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'select.custom'
```

Answer (score 3):

You using _inherit = 'select.custom' which is inheriting existing object so you have to make sure that object table is already loaded in memory.

Use _name instead _inherit to load that table.

Bests,

Comment: Thanks and however, I too have figured it out a while ago and now I updated my code as below but still getting the same error

1. removed the line `_inherit = 'select.custom'` from **select_custom.py**
2. removed the line `<field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>` from **select_custom_view.xml**

but still showing same error. Could you please check it out ?

Comment: Creating what kind of view, your view definition is wrong.

Comment: damn ! need to clear the basics first before playing around :(  thanks though :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is related to file name. Everything is looks good apart from file name which you gave. You have to give file name `__init__.py` instead of `__init.py`

After this if your issue is remain same then check your inherited module. There might be some issue regarding inheritance.

Apart from that your `.xml` file looks good. No changes is needed in that.